# Deploying Java applications without including production credentials in VC

Tags: java, deployment, web-deployment

Am using Maven and Jenkins to manage deployment of my web application.  Essentially:

- When deploy is triggered, CI box checks the code out of version control.
- If code passes tests, it triggers the Maven release plugin to build a versioned war, and puts it in our local nexus repo
- In same build, pulls the artifact from nexus, and copies the artifact into tomcat, triggering Tocmat to re-explode war.

This works fine, and using this technique I can use maven to replace the appropriate environment specific configurations, so long as they are within the project.  However, my SysAdmin considers it a security risk to have production credentials in VC. Instead, we would prefer to store the production credentials on the production machines that will be using them.  I can imagine writing a simple bash script to ssh into the service box, and soft link the conf file onto the classpath, but this seems like a pretty inelegant solution.

Is this reasonable?  Is there a better/more standard way of acheiving this?  Is it actually a security risk to hold production credentials in VC?

Answer (score 0):

You have your conf file on your production server at some location. This location could be a property too.

If there is no specific reason for not loading it as a file from disk rather than loading as a resource from classpath, you could create a separate [Maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)  `production` that would [filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) the location replacing it with the file path for your production server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a security risk to have production credentials in version control. It frees your developers to do pretty much whatever they want to production. Regulations like HIPAA in medicine or PCI for e-commerce or SoX for public US companies would frown on that. Your sys-admin is reasonable to as well.

The basic strategy is to externalize this configuration and have the deployment process roll in the environment specific data.

Having that information on the production server itself is an ok, but not great solution. It's a good fit when you have just one target server. Once you have a bunch, there's a maintenance headache. Whenever env. specific data changes, it has to be updated on every server. You also need to be sure to only have env. specific information in there or else changes developers make to early environments may not be communicated to the sys-admin to change at deployment time leading to production deployment errors.

This is where, I think, Hudson lets you down from a continuous delivery perspective. Some of the commercial tools, including my company's [uBuild/AnthillPro](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/build/default.html), formally track different environments and would securely let the sys-admin configure the production credentials and developers configure the dev credentials with the tool. Likewise the application release automation tools like our [uDeploy](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/deploy/default.html) that would pull builds out of Hudson and deploy them, should have this kind of per environment configuration baked.

In these scenarios, most of the property / xml files have generic config, and the deployment engine substitutes env. specific data in as it deploys.

Adding a new tool for just this problem is probably overkill, but the basic strategy of externalizing environment specific info into a central place where it can be looked up a deployment time could work. Since you're a Maven shop, you might consider stashing some of this in your Maven repo in an area locked down for access by only operations. Then pull the latest config for the appropriate environment at deployment time.

You have a range of options here. Consider how things vary by environment; what varies by server; what needs to be secured, what changes with time on the dev side, etc. And please, please, please sit down with your sys-admin and work out a solution together. You each have insight the other doesn't and the end solution will be better for the cooperation.